# bash script to send the log file as mail content, formatted (specific color coding)

Tags: bash, shell, sendmail

```
cat run_summary.txt | unix2dos | mail -s "summary log" email_id@gmail.com
```

This command is sending the mail as message body. However, it is not formatted. run_summary.txt has lines with columns but in email it is not same as in log file. log file is in this format as below.

```
below is the summary of log files:
#empty line
date time mon
12   09   jan
07   22   apr
```

Comment: `TAB` display is mail client dependent, may be rendered as any number of spaces. For alignment, unless the receiving mail client uses a true text terminal or use a fixed-width font, alignment is not warranted. Usually you can format text/plain MIME parts counting characters and expect client having a fixed-width font though.

Comment: Can you let me know if there is a functionality in bash scripting to read file and send it to mail in columns/tables. or if not can create a .html and send that to mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cat` command is not needed. You should redirect the file to the `mail` command.

Furthermore the `unix2dos` command can handle files, not strings. In your case the `unix2dos` command gets a string because of `cat` command. Please read the man page of `unix2dos` command: https://linux.die.net/man/1/unix2dos

**Example:**

```
mail -s "summary log" my_mail@gmail.com < run_summary.txt
```

**If you really need the `unix2dos` command then you can do this:**

```
unix2dos run_summary.txt && mail -s "summary log" my_mail@gmail.com < run_summary.txt
```

**FYI:**
In the above example the original content in `run_summary.txt` file will be overwritten. If you want to create a new file, you should use the `-n` flag.
Eg.:

```
Convert a.txt and write to e.txt.

unix2dos -n a.txt e.txt
```

I have used the same txt file as you and the mail contains the following content:

```
date time mon
12   09   jan
07   22   apr
```

Comment: If the log file has more than one whitespace between the columns, it is not aligned with same whitespaces in mail.